# wp8: smsComposeTask on windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

When ever I used this below piece of code, it launches the messaging app, i don't want that. I want to send SMS within my app. How to do that. any ideas ?

Code

```
         SmsComposeTask smsComposeTask = new SmsComposeTask();
         smsComposeTask.To = "9012345566778"; // Mention here the phone number to whom the sms is to be sent
         smsComposeTask.Body = "Hello! How are you"; // the string containing the sms body
         smsComposeTask.Show(); // this will invoke the native sms edtior
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't send a SMS directly from your app. Using the `SmsComposeTask` (and therefore displaying the message hub) is the only way.

Comment: then how to send the app directly from my app ?

Comment: @user2655873 - You can't unless you have a web service that sends text and your app calls that web service. There's no way to do it using the built in APIs in the current SDK.

Comment: @keyboardP so there is no way to create an app like (this)[http://store.ovi.com/content/36405]

Comment: @user2655873 - I assume that app sends the SMS automatically. That's not possible here, probably for security reasons. Your app can set everything up like you've done but the user has the have the final input to confirm they want the text sent.

Comment: @keyboardP i wanna do flash sms app like that. so that is impoosible uh ?

Comment: @user2655873 - That link's not working anymore but this is the bottom line. You *cannot* send a text without the user confirming it using the built in APIs of the current SDK (no matter how many times you ask ;))

Comment: @user2655873 - Erm, strange comment. I'm answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think KooKiz is right. windows phone is cared for its security.